# How can I make my header of my react app responsive?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I am working on an app where I need to make the header collapse on mobile view, I have tried different stylings all with no desired results. This is the [desktop view](https://imge.to/i/TdpcA)

Then here is what the [mobile view](https://imge.to/i/TdC21) I need to make responsive.
My UI is built on antd

.jsx

```
<Header className={MAIN_NAV}>
  <Menu className={LEFT_NAV_MENU}>
    <Item>
        item 1
    </Item>
    <Item>
        Item 2
    </Item>
  </Menu>                
  <Menu className={RIGHT_NAV_MENU}>
    <Item>
        item 3
    </Item>
    <Item>
        Item 4
    </Item>
  </Menu>       
</Header>
```

.css

```
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left-nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right-nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* rules go here */
  .MAIN_NAV {
     width: 100px;
  }
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp